# Selecting the data frame row with the earliest time value for a set period

Tags: r, pandas, po

I have a df in r with numerous records with the below format, with 'arrival_time' values for a 12 hour period'.

| id | arrival_time | wait_time_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-20 12:02:00 | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-02-20 12:04:00 | 5 |
| 99900 | 2020-02-20 23:47:00 | 8 |
| 10000 | 2020-02-20 23:59:00 | 21 |

I would like to create a new df that has a row for each 15 minute slot of the arrival time period and the wait_time_value of the record with the earliest arrival time in that slot. So, in the above example, the first and last row of the new df would look like:

| id | period_start | wait_time_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-20 12:00:00 | 10 |
| 48 | 2020-02-20 23:45:00 | 8 |

I have used the below code to achieve this for the mean average wait time for all records in each 15 minute range, but i'm not sure how to select the value for the earliest record?

```
df$period_start <- align.time(df$arrival_time- 899, n = 60*15)

avgwait_df <- aggregate(wait_time_value ~ period_start, df, mean)
```

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), remove only `NaN`s and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'])

df = (df.resample('15Min', on='arrival_time')['wait_time_value']
        .first()
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(name='wait_time_value'))
print (df)
         arrival_time  wait_time_value
0 2020-02-20 12:00:00             10.0
1 2020-02-20 23:45:00              8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
   group_by(period_start) %>%
   summarise(wait_time = min(wait_time_value))
```

Comment: Would this not provide the minimum wait_time_value rather than the value for the earliest arrival time?

Comment: My understanding from your question was that that was what you wanted. You can get the earliest arrival time by substituting `wait_time_value` with `arrival_time` in the `min` function.